# Bash: log a message between execution of two commands in a pipeline

Tags: bash, curl, stdout, stdin, tar

EDIT: Thanks for all the answers. I now understand that what I want is nonsense.

I have the following command that downloads and unpacks an archive:

`curl -fSL "$uri" | tar -xz`

What I want is to display a message after downloading and then unpack the downloaded archive with tar.

I know that it's possible to save the downloaded archive to a file, do anything else and then untar it. But is it possible to do this without saving to a file? With stdin and stdout?

Comment: Use stderr, not stdout, for informational messages.

Comment: The thing you're asking for is impossible because there's no such thing as "between" these two commands. The `curl` and the `tar` commands *run at the same time*. The moment `curl` writes a block of content it downloaded to its stdout, `tar` reads that content and starts unpacking it, while `curl` is still busy downloading more.

Comment: ...now, one can certainly have an additional pipe component responsible for status tracking (running at the same time as both curl and tar), and that's a job there are preexisting tools like [`pv`](http://www.ivarch.com/programs/pv.shtml) already written for.

Comment: A pipe is a pipe. `tar`  already starts unpacking when the first bytes have been downloaded.

Comment: ...and breaking it into two parts that happen one after the other would make it slower than leaving it as it is. (Downloading to memory doesn't use I/O bandwidth, and untarring doesn't depend on network bandwidth, so doing both of those things at the same time is more efficient use of resources than doing them one after the other even on a machine with only one CPU core; not to mention that it means you don't need a place to store the downloaded-but-not-yet-unpacked contents).

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/331790/3113 at [unix.se] re: the assertion that log messages belong on stderr, not stdout.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers. I now understand that what I want is nonsense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use groups `{}` to print something after `curl` finished. To display the message in the terminal without passing it to `tar` we can route it via any unused file descriptor (here `3`).

```
{ { curl -fSL "$uri"; echo "download complete" >&3; } | tar -xz; } 3>&1
```

Since `curl` and `tar` run in parallel, the later might finish in the same split second `download complete` is printed. Therefore a simple `curl -fSL "$uri" | tar -xz; echo "Everything done"` might be just as good.

In your question you wrote ...

> display a message after downloading **and then** unpack the downloaded archive

If you really want to pause `tar` until the download is complete, then you could use `sponge` from the package GNU `moreutils`. However, there is no benefit of doing so.

```
{ { curl -fSL "$uri"; echo "download complete" >&3; } | sponge | tar -xz; } 3>&1
```

Comment: ...though if this is a large file (or really, anything _except_ an outright tiny one), `tar` will be almost complete by the time `download complete` prints, so it's not clear what the practical benefit of this is. If `tar` is much slower than `curl`, backpressure on the pipe will force the download to slow down so they both complete at almost the exact same time.

Comment: (Also, if this is intended to be informational logging, stdout -- while being what the user is asking for -- isn't the right place for it).